# How to properly code / debug complicated boolean conditions

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to write an if statement as follows:

```
if(a === 0 && (b === 0 || c === 0)){
    if(b === 0 && c === 0){
        //a, b, and c are equal to 0
    }
    else if(b === 0){
        //only a and b are equal to 0
    }
    else {
        //only a and c are equal to 0
    }
}
else {
    //a doesn't equal 0, but b or c could so we test those
}
```

It doesn't seem to be working in my code which is written in a similar fashion... perhaps I am writing this incorrectly?  It makes sense in my head.  How can I structure my code to avoid confusion like this?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Seems to work just fine to me .. maybe something else is wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/zS5Ty/

Comment: The comment in your final `else` block assumes too much: `a` could very well be `0` there if both `b` and `c` are different from `0`.

Comment: everytime I write it in my code I lose my alerts, but if I un-nest my if statement i get my alerts

Comment: how could a still equal 0 if the first if clause is not met?

Comment: @JakeZeitz the first clause assumes a == 0 and either of the other two do. If neither do, a could still === 0.

Comment: I edited rather liberally to what I think is a more constructive and reusable question.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Are a, b, and c all numeric types. You don't have any as strings `a='0'`, do you?

Comment: @Jake, read the conditional expression again: it is only `true` if `a` is `0` **and** either `b` or `c` are `0`. If both `b` and `c` are non-zero, the expression will be `false` regardless of the value of `a`.

Comment: Jake, use [deMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) to figure out what happens in the final `else` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected your else:

```
if(a === 0 && (b === 0 || c === 0)){
    if(b === 0 && c === 0){
        //a, b, and c are equal to 0
    }
    else if(b === 0){
        //only a and b are equal to 0
    }
    else {
        //only a and c are equal to 0
    }
}
else {
    //   a === 0 and neither b nor c === 0,
    //or a!==0 and neither b nor c === 0,
    //or a!==0 and either b or c or both === 0 
}
```

my proposition:

```
if(a === 0 && (b === 0 || c === 0)){
    if(b === 0 && c === 0){
        //a, b, and c are equal to 0
    }
    else if(b === 0){
        //only a and b are equal to 0
    }
    else {
        //only a and c are equal to 0
    }
} else if (a === 0) {
    //a === 0 and neither b nor c === 0,
} else {
    //   a!==0 and neither b nor c === 0,
    //or a!==0 and either b or c or both === 0 
}
```

Also, you may consider bitwise operations, it might be clearer.
Saludos,

Comment: would it make sense to rewrite the first if statement as `a === 0 || (a === 0 && (b === 0 || c === 0))` in order to cover only a equaling 0?

Comment: the first part of the main IF is correct, you will enter only if a === 0. The problem is the second part: you're not sure whether or not a === 0 since it is not the only excluding condition. You might consider adding an `else if a === 0` in the main if (editing)

Comment: An outer if/else of `a===0` is much more readable to me. YMMV.

Comment: Yes @Marc, I agree. I tried to change the minimum the original structure so the OP is not totally lost :D

Answer (score 2):

I just would have written it in a different coding fashion but what you posted works as expected

http://jsfiddle.net/u2ert/

```
a=0;
b=0;
c=0;

if(a === 0 && (b === 0 || c === 0)){
    if(b === 0 && c === 0){
        alert("//a, b, and c are equal to 0");
    }
    else if(b === 0){
        alert("//only a and b are equal to 0");
    }
    else {
        alert("//only a and c are equal to 0");
    }
}
```

changhe the first three lines to test different assertions

Comment: whithout nesting the if statements and just making a plain sequence of if --- else if --- else if   that would give the same result (maybe little worse performance) but improve much readability

Answer (score 0):

Why write in comments what you can just write in code...?

```
if(a === 0 && (b === 0 || c === 0)){
    if(a === 0 && b === 0 && c === 0){

    }
    else if(a === 0 && b === 0){

    }
    else if (a === 0 && c === 0 ) {

    }
    else {
        console.log("Boolean logic wrong: " + (a===0) + ", " + (b===0) + ", " + (c===0)
        // throw error
    }
}
else {
// print out the values of a, b, c here if you are confused
}
```

Furthermore this is self-debugging so you don't get confused in your boolean logic.

Comment: Why even use the outer if at all if you are repeating the logic in the inner ones?

Comment: -1 the `a === 0...` inside the inner `if`s is redundant - you already know that `a === 0` because of the first `if`

Comment: @alfasin This is by design.  Redundant is better than the reader having to re-remind him/herself of this 3 times while reading dense code.  This is a coping method for dealing with this complex boolean logic.

Comment: So it's a bad design TMHO - that's what comments are for.

Comment: @alfasin the comments clearly did not help the OP.  My code does.  Furthermore see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/coding-without-comments.html - "When you've rewritten, refactored, and rearchitected your code a dozen times to make it easy for your fellow developers to read and understand -- when you can't possibly imagine any conceivable way your code could be changed to become more straightforward and obvious -- then, and only then, should you feel compelled to add a comment explaining what your code does." which is what I've done.

Comment: You got his post all wrong! Jeff doesn't say that comments should be written as last resort. Read it again. And yes, your code should definitely be refactored, that's exactly what I said in my first comment...

Comment: @alfasin bottom line is this code is an improvement because it moves information from the comments that didn't help the OP to code that will actually run and in this case help the OP.  This is a strict improvement.  Redundancy is a form of defensive programming, e.g. null checks, and is warranted in this case per OP's original confusion in managing this.  If you can propose a way to factor this code that does not permit the confusion the OP experienced, which comments are proven do, then please be specific.